# Reading .txt file in every 4 byte in java (4 byte by 4 byte!)

Tags: java, byte, text-files

I tried to use below code that i found it here but my problem wasn't solved.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("fileName.txt");
int currentByte = fileInput.read(buffer);
```

Comment: So go right ahead; nobody's stopping you.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are reading only 4 bytes. Use a `while` loop to keep on reading until the file is completely read.

```
while ((String line = fileInput.read(buffer)) != null) {
    // do something
}
```